# Library to parse Excel Formulas

Tags: language-agnostic, excel-2010

I'm looking to make an AddIn for excel that modifies formulas in cells. Looking at Microsoft's C# and VBA API, I don't even see a Formula object. All I can get is the string that is displayed. Is there a formula parser for excel so that I can mess with something like an AST graph? (I'm language agnostic)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not an accessible built-in parser with an API, but several people have written Excel formula parsers (although the Excel team keep moving the goalposts). See
[Ewbi's c#](http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2007/03/excel_formula_p.html)
 and [Rob Van Gelder's VBA](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/12/05/formula-tokenizer/)