# Print equations components in a text box - excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build a toll to make data analysis. I want to code a text box that will show the values that compound the result of each cell I select. For instance: the cell A1 contains the value "2", the cell B1 contains the value "3" and the cell C1 is =A1*B1 , so "6". I want to add a text box that when I select the cell C1 will bring the text  "2*3" instead of "A1*B1" as it shows in the formula bar. Does anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: How complicated will the formula be? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: The formula won't be so complicated, almost of them are percentages and the data are in the same worksheet, I created a macro to show me just the percentages and hide the values because the base is really messy. Actually, I'm having lots of problem with it, I thought about using "evaluate formula" function and print values, however I don't have any idea how to put it in programming language.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge you're going to face is this: [there is no such thing as a "formula" object in the Excel object model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763479/library-to-parse-excel-formulas), because a formula is a string of essentially arbitrary length and construction, arbitrary levels of nesting and cell references/precedents, each of which may contain a formula (which would require some recursion) or a constant, etc. There is no "general" way to parse these things, although as the linked answer indicates, there are some tools out there which may do something similar.

If you have *specific* cases, you can probably hack something that will work for those cases, but will not be generally applicable to other formulae.  Using a range object's `.DirectPrecendents`, you can trace cells which are referred to in the formula, and using some string functions you may be able to reverse-engineer the formula to constant expressions, and recombine with the operators. HOWEVER, my own testing shows this to be fraught with problems because each of these formula will return the same list of `DirectPrecedents`:

```
=$A1*$B1

=$A$1*$B$1

=$A$1*B1

=A1*B1
```

In those cases (and others), the precedents will be the ranges A1 and B1, respectively, but each of those variants would require that you can identify whether the row and/or column in each precedent is "absolute", at runtime, otherwise, any attempts to use string functions like `Mid`, `Left` and `Instr` will likely fail or return false positives.

If your formula are *exceedingly* simple, and you know you are always dealing with ONLY references, each of which contain constant expressions (not other formula refernces), e.g.:

=$A$1*B$1  'Where A1 contains a constant and so does B1

You could do something like:

```
Function parseFormula(cl as Range, operator as String)
Dim arr, i As Long
Dim ret As String
ret = "="
arr = Split(Mid(cl.Formula, 2), operator)
' yields an array like {$A$1, $B1}

For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    If (i = 0) Then
        ret = ret & Range(arr(i)).Value
    Else
        ret = ret & operator & Range(arr(i)).Value
    End If
Next

parseFormula = ret
End Function
```

Of course this will not work for for formula with mixed operators like:

```
=A1+B1/C1
```

Nor will it work for formula which mix constants and references like:

```
=65+B2/C1
```